# how to filter a list of objects in typesrcript based on values from another array

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I have an objects array as below:

```
 let userTestStatus: { id: number, name: string }[] = [
  { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Started" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "UnKnown" }
];
```

And I have another array like below, which is a result of user's multi selection from a select box:

```
selectedValues=[1,3]
```

I need to filter the `userTestStatus` where id in `1,3`

My resulted object will look like:

```
filteredUserTestStatus: { id: number, name: string }[] = [    
  { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" }      
  { "id": 3, "name": "UnKnown" }
];
```

I'm trying something like:

```
userTestStatus.filter(x=>x.id.) but not sure how it will be done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `includes` method:

```js
// Removed type so it can in browser on stackoverlflow , makes not difference.
let userTestStatus = [ 
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "UnKnown" }
];
let selectedValues = [1, 3]
let result = userTestStatus.filter(x => selectedValues.includes(x.id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @rumi Yes, the `includes` method is not available in that browser, you can use a poly-fill to add it, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes